# On File Move the curly brace layout changes - why?

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2022, code-editor

I have Visual Studio 2022 and Resharper (latest versions). My Code style for curly braces is:

```
if(true) {
    //....
}
```

**!!! While typing end editing code everything works great !!!**

But as soon as I move a code file from one folder to another within the project the curly braces change to:

```
if(true) 
{
    //....
}
```

- I have tried the Option under Tools -> Options / Text Editors -> C# -> Code Style -> Formating -> New lines
- I also have set the corresponding Resharper Options to "K&R Style"
- I tried to disabled all analysers
- I tried to suspend Resharper

Is Visual Studio doing this (and if yes where could be the setting) or is it possible that any Git Tool is changing this? For Git I have "GitHub Desktop" and "TortoiseGit" (But I did not find any Options there)

Comment: First try to suspend R# in "Tools | Options | ReSharper" and see if the problem persists. If it goes away, it's R#'s fault.

Comment: I tried suspending Resharper already - it's still there...